# An unexpected error occured during export

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash, flash-cc

I am working with FlashCC . Recently I try to convert Flash files into Html5 Canvas. I have converted many files but for a particular file I am getting an error as **Unexpected error occured during export.[JSX]** . I have tried all the solutions which ever I have found. I have seen the similar problem which was mentioned earlier in this site, still I am unable to find a solution. 
    I have tried editing the frames one by one to check where I went wrong. Finally the file was converted, but the animation is dead slow. I guess I failed to rectify the problem. Please suggest any . Thank you.

Comment: post your code for us to help you..

Comment: There is no code. I have done everything using Flash .